# "Use of class template requires template argument list" and multiple classes

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I have a header file for a program that utilizes singly linked list. The data that is originally stored in the nodes were integers, however, in an attempt to use the template class, I tried to convert the Node class and AnyList class to template classes; however, when I compile, an error message that says "'Node": use of class template requires template argument list" appears. I've seen examples of template classes, but there's a bit of confusion since I'm trying to make two template classes in one header file.

```
#ifndef ANYLIST_H
#define ANYLIST_H

#include<iostream>
#include <string>           
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node() : data(0), next(NULL) {}
    Node(T& theData, Node *newNext) : data(theData), next(newNext){}
    Node* getNext() const { return next; }
    T getData( ) const { return data; }
    void setData(T& theData) { data = theData; }
    void setNext(Node *newNext) { next = newNext; }
    ~Node(){}
private:
    T data;     
    Node *next; //pointer that points to next node
};

template <typename T>
class AnyList
{   
     friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const AnyList<T>& theList);

public:
    AnyList();  

    void insert(const T& elem);

    int getNumOfElem() const;

    void destroyList();

    ~AnyList();

private:
    Node *first;
    int count;      
 };

#endif
```

Comment: Did those examples also mention that the implementation of templates must reside entirely in the header file?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, `Node<>` and `List<>` are different templates. So you need to forward the template parameter from `List` to `Node`.

Replace

```
Node *first;
```

By

```
Node<T> *first;
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought that was one of my problems. I've tried this and end up getting errors on lines in my .cpp file in functions where I create Node objects. The same error appears.

Comment: template <typename T>
    void AnyList<T>::insert(const T& elem)
    { 
         Node newNode = new Node(elem, nullptr);

     if (first == nullptr)
      first = newNode;
     else
     {
      Node *temp = first;
      while (temp->getNext() != nullptr)
       temp = temp->getNext();
      temp->setNext(newNode);
     }

     ++count;
    }

Comment: @JamieVu you cannot put template implementations in cpp files. You must put everything in the header.